# Collection that allows only unique items in .NET?

Tags: c#, set, hashset

Is there a collection in C# that will not let you add duplicate items to it? For example, with the silly class of

```
public class Customer {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return (FirstName + LastName + Address).GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        Customer C = obj as Customer;
        return C != null && String.Equals(this.FirstName, C.FirstName) && String.Equals(this.LastName, C.LastName) && String.Equals(this.Address, C.Address);
    }
}
```

The following code will (obviously) throw an exception:

```
Customer Adam = new Customer { Address = "A", FirstName = "Adam", LastName = "" };
Customer AdamDup = new Customer { Address = "A", FirstName = "Adam", LastName = "" };

Dictionary<Customer, bool> CustomerHash = new Dictionary<Customer, bool>();
CustomerHash.Add(Adam, true);
CustomerHash.Add(AdamDup, true);
```

But is there a class that will similarly guarantee uniqueness, but without KeyValuePairs? I thought `HashSet<T>` would do that, but having read the docs it seems that class is just a set implementation (*go figure*).

Comment: I don't understand your problem with `HashSet<T>`. MSDN says "The HashSet<T> class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements, and whose elements are in no particular order."

Comment: Can you explain more why `HashSet<T>` is insufficient?

Comment: @mootinator: The `Dictionary<K,V>` class *does not* guarantee any kind of order.

Comment: I guess he just wants to throw an exception when you try to add an existing value... To do this, just check the bool value returned from `HashSet<T>.Add` method and throw when `false`...

Comment: Customer is a seriously flawed example.

Comment: @Henk Holterman - can you elaborate what's flawed about this example?  As I understand it, the main requirements for overriding GetHashCode and Equals is that 2 object *must* have the same hash if they're equal, and that the hash function should be evenly distributed.  Assuming a random distribution of names, what's wrong with this silly implementation?

Comment: It's also strongly recommende to only overload those for _immutable_ types only. A mutable Customer would usually fair better with the default Reference-equality.

Comment: Yes, you're right (obviously).  If you add the customer to the HashSet, and then change it's properties, bad things will happen.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 270, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` is what you're looking for. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) (emphasis added):

> The `HashSet<T>` class provides high-performance set operations. A set is a collection that **contains no duplicate elements**, and whose elements are in no particular order.

Note that the [`HashSet<T>.Add(T item)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) returns a `bool` -- `true` if the item was added to the collection; `false` if the item was already present.

Comment: T item in this case should implement IEquatable interface. If class does not inherit this interface, HashSet<T> adds duplicate elements.

Comment: Or instead of the item implementing `IEquatable`, you can pass a (custom) implementation of `EqualityComparer<T>` instance to the `HashSet<T>` constructor.

Answer (score 19):

How about just an extension method on HashSet?

```
public static void AddOrThrow<T>(this HashSet<T> hash, T item)
{
    if (!hash.Add(item))
        throw new ValueExistingException();
}
```

Answer (score 15):

From the [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) page on MSDN:

> The HashSet(Of T) class provides high-performance set operations. **A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements**, and whose elements are in no particular order.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 5):

If all you need is to ensure uniqueness of elements, then HashSet is what you need.

What do you mean when you say "just a set implementation"? A set is (by definition) a collection of unique elements that doesn't save element order.

Comment: You're completely right; the question was kind of stupid.  Basically, I was looking for something that would throw an exception when a duplicate was added (like Dictionary<TKey, TValue>), but as already mentioned, HashSet<T> returns false on a duplicate add.  +1, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add my 2 cents...

if you need a ValueExistingException-throwing `HashSet<T>` you can also create your collection easily:

```
public class ThrowingHashSet<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private HashSet<T> innerHash = new HashSet<T>();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (!innerHash.Add(item))
            throw new ValueExistingException();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        innerHash.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return innerHash.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        innerHash.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return innerHash.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return innerHash.Remove(item);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return innerHash.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

this can be useful for example if you need it in many places...

Comment: Sure.  I was wondering if anything was built-in, but thank you +1

Answer (score 3):

You can try [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may look into something kind of Unique List as follows

```cs
public class UniqueList<T>
{
    public List<T> List
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    List<T> _internalList;

    public static UniqueList<T> NewList
    {
        get
        {
            return new UniqueList<T>();
        }
    }

    private UniqueList()
    {            
        _internalList = new List<T>();
        List = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T value)
    {
        List.Clear();
        _internalList.Add(value);
        List.AddRange(_internalList.Distinct());
        //return List;
    }

    public void Add(params T[] values)
    {
        List.Clear();
        _internalList.AddRange(values);
        List.AddRange(_internalList.Distinct());
       // return List;
    }

    public bool Has(T value)
    {
        return List.Contains(value);
    }
}
```

and you can use it like follows

```
var uniquelist = UniqueList<string>.NewList;
uniquelist.Add("abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno");
uniquelist.Add("abc","jkl");
var _myList = uniquelist.List;
```

will only return `"abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno"` always even when duplicates are added to it

Answer (score 0):

As an overall check different methods here are 4 ways to check if the collection has not any duplicates:

```
public static bool LinqAny<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new();

    return enumerable.Any(element => !set.Add(element));
}

public static bool LinqAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new();

    return !enumerable.All(set.Add);
}

public static bool LinqDistinct<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.Distinct().Count() != enumerable.Count();
}

public static bool ToHashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.ToHashSet().Count != enumerable.Count();
}
```