# C# Refine class property which is a List<string>

Tags: c#, list

I have a class property:-

```
public List<string> szTypeOfFileList{get;set;}
```

As the name suggest, the property stores user selection of types of Files of interest (.txt, .doc, .rtf, .pdf, etc).

I am trying to assess whether there is way I could refine this List as it is being populated by user entries OR, if I should wait for all entries and then call a separate method to refine the property.

What I mean by this is, let's say a particular user input is ".doc/.docx". Currently, this would be stored in the List as a single string item. However I want it to be stored as two items separately. This will keep the code in one place and wont effect future modules and such.

```
private List<string> _szTypeOfFileList = new List<string>();
public List<string> szTypeOfFileList
{
    get
    {
        return _szTypeOfFileList;
    }
    set
    {
       // Some kind of validation/refining method here ?? //
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:-

Because my FileTypeList is coming from a checkboxList, I had to use a different methodology than the answer I accepted (which pointed me in the right direction).

```
 foreach (object itemchecked in FileTypeList.CheckedItems)
         {
            string[] values = itemchecked.ToString().Split('/');
            foreach(var item in values)
               TransactionBO.Instance.szTypeOfFileList.Add(item);
         }
```

This part of my code is in the UI class before it is passed on to the Business class.

Comment: What's with the `sz` prefix?

Comment: Hungarian notation 2017? Wow...

Comment: I am just a student, go easy on me.:)

Comment: Yeah. Avoid using Hungarian notation, especially in C#. It doesn't even make sense in this context since `sz` means null-terminated strings. C# strings are not null-terminated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that it'll always be split with a "/" character, just use a split on the string.  Including a simple bit of verification to prevent obvious duplicates, you might do something along the lines of:

```
string[] values = x.Split('/');
foreach (string val in values) {
    if (!_szTypeOfFileList.Contains(val.ToLower().Trim())) {
        _szTypeOfFileList.Add(val.ToLower().Trim());
    }
}
```

You can also use an array of characters in place of the '/' to split against, if you need to consider multiple characters in that spot.

Comment: what is x in this context ?

Comment: It's a placeholder for a string from the passed list (eg, from "foreach (string x in value)" within the set).

Comment: thanks Rob. I had to use a different technique since my workflow is a bit different. Adding it to my code above, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider changing the `List` to something more generic. Do they really need a List ...or maybe a collection? array? enumerable ? (have a read through [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/829624/Know-your-collections-from-IEnumerable-to-List-and) )

second, in your `Set` method, you'll want to take their input, break it up and add it. Here comes the question: is a list the best way of doing it ?
What about duplicate data ? do you just add it again? do you need to search for it in order to figure out if you're going to add it ?

Think about dictionary or hashtable, or any of type of collection that will help you out with your data . I would have a read through : [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157787/collection-that-allows-only-unique-items-in-net) (oh my ... wrong link ... nobody complained though ... so much for providing links ... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var extensions = userInput.Split('/').ToList();
```